# Non-equivalent eulerian trails in $K_{2n+1}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Two eulerian trails of $K_{2n+1}$ are defined to be equivalent if the orientations obtained by orienting the edges as traversed by the trails are isomorphic as digraph. How many non-equivalent trails are there?

Comment: The eulerian trails $0\to 1\to 2\to 0$ and $0\to 2\to 1\to 0$ of the complete graph $K_3$ are considered non-equivalent?

Comment: @FreddyBarrera Those would be considered equivalent since they are isomorphic as digraphs (both are just directed triangles).

Comment: @FreddyBarrera, yes they are the same. Number for $K_3$  is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are asking for the number of isomorphism classes of regular tournaments.

There are no exact formulas.  See http://oeis.org/A096368 for counts up to 15 vertices.

The asymptotic number is known.  It is $RT(2n+1)/(2n+1)!$, where $RT(2n+1)$ is given in the abstract of [this paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/rt.pdf).